# How to unwind an Array of Objects in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, multidimensional-array

I want to unwind an array of objects which have arrays of objects nested. The level of nesting is not defined and is not consistent throughout the array.

Here's my sample data

```
var data = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Harshal',
    subjects: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'English',
        chapters: [{
            id: 1,
            name: 'Grammar'
        }, {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Comprehension'
        }]
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Maths',
        chapters: [{
            id: 1,
            name: 'Algebra'
        }, {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Geometry'
        }]
    }]
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Pankaj',
    subjects: [{
        id: 3,
        name: 'Marathi',
        chapters: [{
            id: 1,
            name: 'Kavita',
            topics: [{
                id: 1,
                name: 'Topic 1'
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Hindi',
        chapters: [{
            id: 1,
            name: 'Katha',
            topics: [{
                id: 2,
                name: 'Topic 2'
            }, {
                id: 3,
                name: 'Topic 3'
            }]
        }]
    }]
}];
```

I want to get an output like this:

```
var op = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Harshal',
    subjects: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'English',
        chapters: {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Grammar'
        }
    }
}, {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Harshal',
    subjects: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'English',
        chapters: {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Comprehension'
        }
    }
}, {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Harshal',
    subjects: {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Maths',
        chapters: {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Algebra'
        }
    }
}, {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Harshal',
    subjects: {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Maths',
        chapters: {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Geometry'
        }
    }
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Pankaj',
    subjects: {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Marathi',
        chapters: {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Kavita',
            topics: {
                id: 1,
                name: 'Topic 1'
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Pankaj',
    subjects: {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Hindi',
        chapters: {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Katha',
            topics: {
                id: 2,
                name: 'Topic 2'
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Pankaj',
    subjects: {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Hindi',
        chapters: {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Katha',
            topics: {
                id: 3,
                name: 'Topic 3'
            }
        }
    }
}];
```

I have tried to work with [pull-unwind](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pull-unwind) but I guess there's some issues with it. If anyone has any other ideas, I'm open to implement those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried recursion?

```js
var data = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Harshal',
    subjects: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'English',
        chapters: [{
            id: 1,
            name: 'Grammar'
        }, {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Comprehension'
        }]
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Maths',
        chapters: [{
            id: 1,
            name: 'Algebra'
        }, {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Geometry'
        }]
    }]
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Pankaj',
    subjects: [{
        id: 3,
        name: 'Marathi',
        chapters: [{
            id: 1,
            name: 'Kavita',
            topics: [{
                id: 1,
                name: 'Topic 1'
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Hindi',
        chapters: [{
            id: 1,
            name: 'Katha',
            topics: [{
                id: 2,
                name: 'Topic 2'
            }, {
                id: 3,
                name: 'Topic 3'
            }]
        }]
    }]
}];

function unravel(obj)
{
    var out = [];
    var added = false;
    for(var i in obj) {
 if(obj[i] instanceof Array) {
     for(var j in obj[i]) {
  var r = unravel(obj[i][j]);
  for(var k in r) {
      var a = {};
      for(var key in obj) { // make copy of obj
   a[key] = obj[key];
      }
      a[i] = r[k];
      added = true;
      out.push(a);
  }
     }
 }
    }
    if(!added) {
 out.push(obj);
    }
    return out;
}

var op = [];
for(var i in data)
    op = op.concat(unravel(data[i]));
console.log(JSON.stringify(op, null, 4));
```

Comment: Awesome, that's what I was looking for. I had tried recursion, but messed up my logic somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Weirdly I just found that array has flatMap function which works like a champ.

```
var data = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Harshal',
    subjects: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'English',
        chapters: [{
            id: 1,
            name: 'Grammar'
        }, {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Comprehension'
        }]
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Maths',
        chapters: [{
            id: 1,
            name: 'Algebra'
        }, {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Geometry'
        }]
    }]
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Pankaj',
    subjects: [{
        id: 3,
        name: 'Marathi',
        chapters: [{
            id: 1,
            name: 'Kavita',
            topics: [{
                id: 1,
                name: 'Topic 1'
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Hindi',
        chapters: [{
            id: 1,
            name: 'Katha',
            topics: [{
                id: 2,
                name: 'Topic 2'
            }, {
                id: 3,
                name: 'Topic 3'
            }]
        }]
    }]
}];

data.flatMap(d => d.subjects.map(s => {
    return {
        id: d.id,
        name: d.name,
        subjects: s
    }
}));
```